# How to use phpdotenv library on my whole project?

Tags: php, frameworks, autoload, phpdotenv

I started a project using composer and donlowaded the package vlucas/phpdotenv. I would like to call the $_ENV['name'] for example in my whole project without needing to instantiate the dot env in every class like that:

```
$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

How can I achieve that like a laravel framework does for example?

Another question is I tough I needed to import my autoload `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` in order to call `use Dotenv\Dotenv;`...

How is that I can use Dotenv without the require autoload in my classes?

EDIT added index.php:

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

How do I autostart it now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, you have a bootstrap file where you include both Composer's `autoload.php` and other common stuff, e.g. the instantiation of `Dotenv`. This can be an `index.php` file which handles all incoming requests (the most common pattern you will find in frameworks, Laravel does the same: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8e5510458e1a4c0bf4b78024d9b0cf56102c8207/public/index.php#L34) or some other file you will include in all your `.php` files that are handling requests (if you are not using a common `index.php`).

If you want to learn more about how frameworks work, I suggest you browse & read their code. You can start with something smaller (like Slim).

---

***LATER EDIT - DUMMY TUTORIAL:***

Alright, let's build a very basic project:

**Step 1.** We start with the following:

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "example/project",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.3"
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

echo 'Hello world!';
var_dump($_ENV);
```

**.env**

```
SAMPLE_ENV_VAR = some_value
```

The file structure you have after you run `composer install`:

```
project_root_folder/
 - vendor/
 - .env
 - composer.json
 - composer.lock
 - index.php
```

Given this state, when you visit your index.php in the browser (let's say http://localhost/ or http://localhost/index.php), it should run without errors and you should also see the custom env var we have declared in the `.env` file.

---

**Step 2.** Add basic routing:

**index.php**

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

// Figure out the requested page; fallback to the home page.
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 'Home';

if ($page == 'Home') {
    echo 'This is the home page.';
}
elseif ($page == 'Books/index') {
    echo 'This is the books index page.';
}
elseif ($page == 'Books/detail') {
    echo 'This is the detail page for book with ID: ' . $_GET['book_id'];
}
else {
    echo 'NOT FOUND :(';
}
```

If you now visit http://localhost/ or http://localhost/index.php or http://localhost/index.php?page=Home, you should see the home page.
If you visit http://localhost/index.php?page=Books/index, you should see the books index page and so on...

---

**Step 3.** Move pages' logic out to separate controllers:
**index.php**

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

// Figure out the requested page; fallback to the home page.
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 'Home';

// We require the necessary controller class file and call its appropriate method:
if ($page == 'Home') {
    require __DIR__.'/src/controllers/Home.php';
    (new Home())->index();
}
elseif ($page == 'Books/index') {
    require __DIR__.'/src/controllers/Books.php';
    (new Books())->index();
}
elseif ($page == 'Books/detail') {
    require __DIR__.'/src/controllers/Books.php';
    (new Books())->detail();
}
else {
    echo 'NOT FOUND :(';
}
```

**src/Controllers/Home.php**

```
<?php

class Home
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'This is the home page.';
    }
}
```

**src/Controllers/Books.php**

```
<?php

class Books
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'This is the books index page.';
    }

    public function detail()
    {
        echo 'This is the detail page for book with ID: ' . $_GET['book_id'];
    }
}
```

The new file structure:

```
project_root_folder/
 - src/
   - Controllers/
     - Home.php
     - Books.php
 - vendor/
 - .env
 - composer.json
 - composer.lock
 - index.php
```

---

**Step 4.** Make use of composer and PSR-4 autoloading (in order to get rid of the manual requires):

Notice the additions to `composer.json` and the added namespaces to the `.php` files.

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "example/project",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Example\\Project\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to run `composer dump-autoload` in order to "apply" the above changes.

**src/Controllers/Home.php**

```
<?php

namespace Example\Project\Controllers;

class Home
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'This is the home page.';
    }
}
```

**src/Controllers/Books.php**

```
<?php

namespace Example\Project\Controllers;

class Books
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'This is the books index page.';
    }

    public function detail()
    {
        echo 'This is the detail page for book with ID: ' . $_GET['book_id'];
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

// Figure out the requested page; fallback to the home page.
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 'Home';

if ($page == 'Home') {
    (new \Example\Project\Controllers\Home())->index();
}
elseif ($page == 'Books/index') {
    (new Example\Project\Controllers\Books())->index();
}
elseif ($page == 'Books/detail') {
    (new Example\Project\Controllers\Books())->detail();
}
else {
    echo 'NOT FOUND :(';
}
```

---

Step 5. Load & call the controllers dynamically.

**index.php**

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

// Figure out the requested page; fallback to the home page.
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 'Home';

// Figure out the controller name and the method name.
if (strpos($page, '/') === FALSE) {
    $page = $page . '/index';
}
[$controllerName, $method] = explode('/', $page);

$controllerClassName = '\\Example\\Project\\Controllers\\' . $controllerName;

if (class_exists($controllerClassName) && method_exists($controllerClassName, $method)) {
    (new $controllerClassName())->$method();
}
else {
    echo 'NOT FOUND :(';
}
```

After this change we can introduce new controllers (e.g. `Faq`) without the need to modify `index.php` anymore. Implementing the controller class will be sufficient for the http://localhost/index.php?page=Faq URL to work.

---

... and so on.

The above is a simple and incomplete example for routing. A complete routing mechanism is much more complex than this, nevertheless it can provide you basic understanding on how to use composer, auto-loading, routing.

Comment: I have alredy created the index.php (edited my question with it) but still don't know how to use it for all my project or how to autoexecute it, can u provide an example please?

Comment: I've edited my response with a mini tutorial.